# How to get first index of Binary Search's results?

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have some problems. I have 2 list such as:

```
List<int> firstList = new List<int> { 1, 2, 2, 3, 5};

List<int> secondList = new List<int> { 2, 3, 1 };
```

⇒ True result is: `{1, 3, 0}`

I would like to get the first index of numbers in secondList that exists in firstList. I used `list.BinarySearch()` but the result was `{2, 3, 0}`.

Comment: BinarySearch does not guaranteed the first match, It's used for searching and inserting in a sorted collection.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  List<int> firstList = new List<int> { 1, 2, 2, 3, 5};
  List<int> secondList = new List<int> { 2, 3, 1 };

  var output = secondList.Select(item => firstList.IndexOf(item)); // [1 , 3 , 0]
```

You can replace the `IndexOf` with a BinarySearch logic, but BinarySearch returns the first matched element index, so you won't get the lowest number, IndexOf does return the lowest matching index.

Comment: Now if a number in secondList that is no exists in firstList I have to return -1. I should use SingleorDefault ?

Comment: IndexOf will return you -1, go ahead and try

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when the list contains duplicate values as in your case, the `BinarySearch` method will return the index of any of the matching values (non deterministic).

To get the desired result, you could create and use a custom extension method like this:

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static int BinarySearchFirst<T>(this List<T> source, T item, IComparer<T> comparer = null)
    {
        if (comparer == null) comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;
        int index = source.BinarySearch(item, comparer);
        while (index > 0 && comparer.Compare(source[index], source[index - 1]) == 0)
            index--;
        return index;
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
var result = secondList.Select(x => firstList.BinarySearchFirst(x)).ToList();
// { 1, 3, 0 }
```

Answer (score 1):

C++ has a standard library function for this called [`lower_bound()`.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/)

Here's a C# implementation. This is useful if you are searching large collections:

```
public static int LowerBound<T>(IList<T> values, T target, int first, int last) 
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    int left = first;
    int right = last;

    while (left < right)
    {
        int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
        var middle = values[mid];

        if (middle.CompareTo(target) < 0)
            left = mid + 1;
        else
            right = mid;
    }

    return left;
}
```

That doesn't return -1 for elements that it doesn't find, so to fix that we can wrap it like so:

```
public static int LowerBoundOrMinusOne<T>(IList<T> values, T target, int first, int last)
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    int result = LowerBound(values, target, first, last);

    if (result >= last || result < first || values[result].CompareTo(target) != 0)
        return -1;

    return result;
}
```

Here is how you use it:

```
List<int> firstList = new List<int> { 1, 2, 2, 3, 5 };
List<int> secondList = new List<int> { 2, 3, 1 };

List<int> result = secondList
    .Select(value => LowerBoundOrMinusOne(firstList, value, 0, firstList.Count))
    .ToList();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));
```

Of course, this is mainly of benefit to large lists because it has an O(Log2(N)) rather than an O(N) complexity.

Comment: Thank you. It is very usefull

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through second array and get index of element in first array:

```
foreach (int item in secondList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(firstList.IndexOf(item));
}
```

Comment: IndexOf has an O(n) complexity. Instead, BinarySearch has an O(log n) complexity.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large `firstList` and so you have to use `BinarySearch` try *amending* it: find out the item (which is *not guaranteed* to be the leftmost one) by `BinarySearch`, then move to the left while having read the same item:

```
  List<int> firstList = new List<int> { 1, 2, 2, 3, 5 };

  List<int> secondList = new List<int> { 2, 3, 1, 123 };

  var result = secondList
    .Select(item => firstList.BinarySearch(item))
    .Select(index => index < 0 ? -1 : Enumerable
       .Range(0, index + 1)     // we have to scan [0..index] at the worst case
       .Select(i => index - i)  // scan in reverse
       .TakeWhile(i => firstList[index] == firstList[i]) // take while items are the same
       .Last()); // finally, we want the last item
```

Test

```
  // 1, 3, 0, -1
  Console.Write(String.Join(", ", result));
```

Comment: He wants `-1` in case no element was found

Comment: @Ofiris: thank you, I see; just a small modification of the ternary operator